# Print Message inside MySQL Function

Tags: mysql, function

Is there a way to print some data in a MySQL function like MSSQL's `print`. `SELECT` statement is okay in SPs but not in functions. Thank you.

Comment: The answer is "no," but if you have a use case for this, please elaborate and perhaps we can come up with a more useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always can create table log(id,atime timestamp,message text) and do insert